# Conflict between local Tor port 9150 and docker Tor using localhost tor_proxy_port

Tags: docker, ubuntu, tor

I have ubuntu 22 box running tor on 9150.  I have also installed Umbrel that uses a tor proxy port as registered in docker_compose.yml that points to 127.0.0.1:$tor_proxy_port.

Due to this localhost proxy port for tor, Umbrel cannot be reached due to the tor conflicting ports unless I uninstall tor on the local host.  But that causes problems with my local apps that are needing tor.

docker_compose.yml
ports:
- "127.0.0.1:$TOR_PROXY_PORT:$TOR_PROXY_PORT"

Umbrel logs on Start up:
Starting Docker services...

dashboard is up-to-date
auth is up-to-date
Starting tor ...
Starting tor ... error

ERROR: for tor  Cannot start service tor_proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint tor (41f14eab9.....1c231e): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:9050: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for tor_proxy  Cannot start service tor_proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint tor (41f14eab9.....1c231e): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:9050: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Failed to start containers

How can I edit docker_compose.yml for the tor proxy port or edit tor (maybe thru torrc) to get local tor to play nice with docker tor?

Comment: The two `ports:` numbers can be different.  The second number _must_ match the port the service in the container is listening on (your your example it must be fixed at 9050) but the first one can be anything that's not already in use on the host.

Comment: Based on your note - I edited the ports line and took out the tor_proxy_port references and just assigned a port:
                ports:
                 - "127.0.0.1:9052:9050"
Then stopped and started umbrel and it worked.   I can access the umbrel both local and over onion with no tor conflict.  Thanks!